# SQL Distinct value over joined tables

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to get the `DISTINCT` value of one column in a table. This column however is INNER JOINED from another table through an `id`.

When I try to use the `DISTINCT` on the column, it produces the same results because `DISTINCT` also takes into account the unique identifier ID. Is there any work around for this to just get the `DISTINCT` value of a column from a joined table???

EG.

```
SELECT val1, b.val2, val3
  FROM TABLE 1 
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val2 
          FROM TABLE 2) AS b ON val1 = b.val2
```

Comment: No, `SELECT DISTINCT val2 FROM TABLE 2` does not also take into account the ID. When you run just that subquery, you will get only the DISTINCT values you want. What do you want your results to look like?

Comment: its not the default id is another id field that has values. So it takes it into account, i also need this id field as it is the only way to link the two tables.

Comment: @kjt15: ASP.NET doesn't tell me what database.  I assume MS SQL Server...

Comment: Provide an example of data from `table1` and `table2` and an example of result. Because `DISTINCT` DOES NOT take into account any other fields from `table2` except `val2`. Sure, `val2` will be presented in result some times if there are some rows with the same `val1` for example. So - provide an example of source data and an example of expected result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide my solution: 
I ended up using a nested distinct through a join and all the unnested values (all 20+) of them had to be wrapped around a MIN(x), seeing as those values didnt matter that much, so long as only one distinct value was returned.

Answer (score 10):

Try throwing in a GROUP BY instead of a DISTINCT:

```
SELECT val1
     , b.val2
     , val3
  FROM TABLE 1 
  JOIN (SELECT val2 
          FROM TABLE 2 GROUP BY val2) AS b ON val1 = b.val2
```

Comment: Not sure why but the GROUP BY always causes an error. Im doing this through the Query Builder is Visual Studio 2010

Comment: it says: Column 'x' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The result is the same -- `GROUP BY val2` will just return distinct/unique `val2` values.

Comment: @OMGPonies - I assumed it would first group then do the join.  What is the order of operations between DISTINCT, GROUP BY and ON?

Comment: In this example, the JOIN will be on the result of the DISTINCT/GROUP BY.  Either DISTINCT/GROUP BY would have to be added to the outer query to affect the final result.  If I understand your question correctly...